# Cycle trough comma separated list in a loop-repeat environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, tikz-knots

I'm trying to cycle trough a comma separated list in an `loop-repeat` environment. But all label names are printed at once and the cycle number is added.

How can I define and link the list of variable names to the strands accordingly? I tried several variations but with no success yet.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
%\documentclass[convert={density=1200,size=4320x3200,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0,>=latex']
%
\draw[fill=white] (0,0) rectangle (5,6);
%
\begin{knot}[ %draft mode=crossings,
clip width=5,
clip radius=6pt]
%
\def\j{$unused$,$\alpha$,$\beta$,$\gamma$}
\edef\x{1}
\loop
\edef\x{\the\numexpr\x+1}
\strand [red,->]
    (1,\x) coordinate (w\x) -- coordinate (e\x)(4,\x) node[anchor=left,above,at start]{\j{\x}};
\ifnum\x<4\repeat
%
\strand [thick,->] (2,1) -- (2,5);
\strand [thick,->] (3,1) -- (3,5);
%\flipcrossings {2}
\end{knot}
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposal works, in principle, but there are syntax errors. If you want an array of strings, you need to wrap the entries in `"`. Then the array entries can be read off with

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mc}{{\j}[\numexpr\x-2]}
```

which differs from your expression: you need extra `{` and `}`, and you need to access the entries with square brackets, and the first entry has index 0, hence the `\numexpr\x-1`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
%\documentclass[convert={density=1200,size=4320x3200,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0,>=latex']
%
\draw[fill=white] (0,0) rectangle (5,6);
%
\begin{knot}[ %draft mode=crossings,
clip width=5,
clip radius=6pt]
%
\def\j{"$\alpha$","$\beta$","$\gamma$"}
\edef\x{1}
\loop
\edef\x{\the\numexpr\x+1}
\strand [red,->]
    (1,\x) coordinate (w\x) -- coordinate (e\x)(4,\x) 
    node[anchor=left,above,at start]{\pgfmathsetmacro{\mc}{{\j}[\numexpr\x-2]}%
    \mc};
\ifnum\x<4\repeat
%
\strand [thick,->] (2,1) -- (2,5);
\strand [thick,->] (3,1) -- (3,5);
%\flipcrossings {2}
\end{knot}
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you again! You are my hero of the day!

Answer (score 1):

I can propose an `expl3` based solution that avoids quirks with `\edef` or `\def` and also issues about names of variables.

In `\xloop` there are an optional argument (starting point, default 1), a mandatory one for the end point and the code to execute, where `#1` refers to the current value in the loop. A further optional argument for the step can be added easily, if you need it.

The command `\listdefine` should be self-explanatory; the command `\listextract` extracts the requested item from the list (index starting from 1); in the second argument to `\listextract` one can use arithmetic expressions.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed for LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% looping through integers
\NewDocumentCommand{\xloop}{O{1}mm}
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
% define lists
\NewDocumentCommand{\listdefine}{mm}
 {
  \clist_clear_new:c { l_nivek_list_#1_clist }
  \clist_set:cn { l_nivek_list_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }
% extracting items from lists
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\listelement}{mm}
 {
  \clist_item:cn { l_nivek_list_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0,>=latex']

\draw[fill=white] (0,0) rectangle (5,6);

\begin{knot}[ %draft mode=crossings,
  clip width=5,
  clip radius=6pt
]
%
\listdefine{j}{$\alpha$,$\beta$,$\gamma$}
\xloop[2]{4}{
  \strand [red,->]
    (1,#1) coordinate (w#1) -- coordinate (e#1)(4,#1) 
     node[anchor=left,above,at start]{\listelement{j}{#1-1}};
}
%
\strand [thick,->] (2,1) -- (2,5);
\strand [thick,->] (3,1) -- (3,5);
\end{knot}
%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]